# Lost my toolbar in Jgrasp how to get it back?

Tags: jgrasp

lost my toolbar buttons in Jgrasp I accidentally clicked the "X" button on the thought it was the exit button checked settings but too afraid to click a button that will change the environment again, here's the result, [image: only open file remains]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The toolbar is language specific, so the toolbar goes away unless you have a file open. Since you pressed the X button, the file was closed, and thus, the toolbar went away. If you open up a new file (By clicking the folder icon on the far top left and selecting the previous file), it will bring back the toolbar.